# React JSX + Titaniumifier

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs, grunt-browserify

Our current infrastructure relies on Titanium for native. I am trying to convert my node project into CommonJS using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-titaniumifier . However, it fails on the JSX:

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <EnergyChart width="1000" data={JSONData.data} customerID={customerID} lineColor='#FF0' height="500" marginTop="20" marginLeft="50" marginBottom="20" marginRight="20" />
  </div>
);
```

Browserify works fine, as it uses the transform like so:

```
browserify: {


  app: {
    src: 'app/App.js', dest: 'dist/bundle.js',
    options: {
        transform: ['grunt-less-browserify', require('grunt-react').browserify],
    }
  },

}
```

For titaniumifier, I have the following:

```
"titaniumifier": {
  "module": {
    files: {
      // The package is in "." and the zipfile will be written in "."
      ".": "."

    },

  },
  options: {
      transform: [ require('grunt-react').browserify],
  }
}
```

However running `grunt titaniumifier:module` returns

> Fatal error: Parsing file
>   /Users/rduckworth/Projects/titanium-d3/app/App.js: Unexpected token
>   (23:6)

which is the JSX code above.

Is there anyway I can get Titaniumifier to compile the JSX like browserify does?

Answer (score 1):

@rickyduck Creator and maintainer of [*titaniumifier*](https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier) here. I’m so sorry I missed this question.

You can enable Babel transpilation for you package/module by using [the same syntax I show on the Wiki](https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier/wiki/Host-mode#usage-with-babeljs) for enabling it for your app.

Long story short:

1. Add *Babel* as a dependency
2. Use the `titaniumifier.transforms` object of your *package.json*

An example:

```
{
  "devDependencies": { ".." },
  "titaniumifier": {
    "transforms": {
      "babel": { "presets": [ "es2015" ] }
    }
  }
}
```